# Extract array values that are nearly identical

Tags: python, arrays, numpy-ndarray

I have this numpy array:

```
a = np.array([[8.04,9], [2.02,3], [8,10], [2,3], [8.12,18], [8.04,18],[2,8],[11,14]])
```

From this array, I would like to find nearly identical row values (not more than 0.05 for the first index AND not more than 1 for the second index) and create new sub-arrays.

For this example, this would give 6 different arrays (which could be part of large array).

```
a1 = [[8.04,9],[8,10]]
a2 = [[2.02,3],[2,3]]
a3 = [8.12,18]
a4 = [8.04,18]
a5 = [2,8]
a6 = [11,14]
```

Is there a way to do that ?
Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP asks for grouping pairs, not simply printing pairs, so the solution proposed by John Zwink is incomplete. To get the complete answer, the idea is to convert ndarrays into a hashable equivalent (e.g. tuple) and combine all them into a set to avoid duplication. Here:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[8.04,9], [2.02,3], [8,10], [2,3], [8.12,18], [8.04,18],[2,8],[11,14]])

groups = set()
for pair in a:
    cond1 = np.isclose(a[:,0], pair[0], atol=0.05)
    cond2 = np.isclose(a[:,1], pair[1], atol=1.000000001)
    groups.add(tuple(map(tuple, a[cond1 & cond2])))

print(groups)
```

Result:

```
{((8.12, 18.0),),
 ((8.04, 18.0),),
 ((2.02, 3.0), (2.0, 3.0)),
 ((11.0, 14.0),),
 ((8.04, 9.0), (8.0, 10.0)),
 ((2.0, 8.0),)}
```

**Note:** I added an arbitrary epsilon to the second condition, to get the same grouping as wanted in the OP

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple method:

```
for pair in a:
    cond1 = np.isclose(a[:,0], pair[0], atol=0.05)
    cond2 = np.isclose(a[:,1], pair[1], atol=1)
    print(a[cond1 & cond2])
```

With deduplication:

```
done = np.zeros(len(a), bool)
for ii, pair in enumerate(a):
    if done[ii]:
        continue
    cond = np.isclose(a[:,0], pair[0], atol=0.05)
    cond &= np.isclose(a[:,1], pair[1], atol=1)
    print(a[cond])
    done |= cond
```

Comment: This duplicates printing lists that have more than one element

Comment: @CDJB: Indeed.  I've now added a version with deduplication.